# About finding a point on a line AB that meets a known criteria

Tags: geometry

Here is a problem that I am struggling with:

1. Find a point C on line AB so that $AB^2 + BC^2 = 2
   .AC^2$

I started by using Proposition 7 from Book II from Euclid's elements:

$AB^2 + BC^2 = AC^2 + 2.AB.BC$

For the left side to also be equal to $2.AC^2$ as required by the problem, it implies that:

$AC^2 = 2.AB.BC$

I know how to use propostion 11 in Book II to solve for finding a C such that:

$AC^2 = AB.BC$ but I could not figure out how to find a C that would enable $AC^2 = 2.AB.BC$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You don't know in advance that the desired point C is between the given points A and B. Did you try to find C to the right of both A and B?

Comment: This problem is specifically about finding a point between A and B on the line AB. I posted a separate problem about finding a point C on AB produced to C (right of B).

Comment: Do you want a geometrical solution, or can I use just simple algebra (quadratic equation)?

Comment: A geometric solution please. No algebra or coordinate geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First construct a square with a side $AB$ and call it $ABDB'$, where point $D$ is diagonally opposite to $A$. Construct $C$ between $AB$ with the given condition

$$AB^2 + BC^2 = 2AC^2$$

And a similar point $C'$ on the adjacent side $AB'$, symmetric about the diagonal $AD$.

[image: Diagram of extra constructions]

By the Pythagorean theorem, the LHS becomes

$$AB^2+BC^2 = BD^2 + BC^2 = CD^2$$

And the RHS becomes

$$2AC^2 = AC^2 + AC'^2 = CC'^2$$

Together with the diagonal symmetry that $CD=C'D$, $\triangle CDC'$ is an equilateral triangle inscribed inside square $ABDB'$.

Then construct points on a square grid around point $A$, as shown in the diagram above. Both the horizontal and vertical distances between grid line have distance $AB$.

By considering the angles inside right angle $\angle D$ and the diagonal symmetry, $\angle B'DC' = \frac{90^\circ-60^\circ}{2} = 15^\circ$. And so $\angle B'C'D = 90^\circ-15^\circ = 75^\circ$. Then by symmetry about vertical $AB'$, $\angle B'C'E = \angle B'C'D = 75^\circ$.

By considering all the angles at point $C'$,

$$\begin{align*}
\angle EC'C &= 360^\circ - \angle EC'B' - \angle B'C'D - \angle DC'C\\
&= 360^\circ - 75^\circ - 75^\circ - 60^\circ\\
&= 150^\circ
\end{align*}$$

Since $EC'=EC'$, $C'D=C'C$ and $\angle EC'D = \angle EC'C = 150^\circ$, so $\triangle EC'D \cong \triangle EC'C$ (SAS). This gives the remaining side of $\triangle EC'C$

$$EC = ED = 2AB$$

By the Pythagorean theorem on right-angled $\triangle EFC$ (actually a $30-60-90$ triangle),

$$FC = \sqrt{EC^2-EF^2} = \sqrt{2^2-1^2}AB =\sqrt3AB$$

And the required point $C$ is at

$$\begin{align*}
AC &= FC-FA = \left(\sqrt3 -1\right) AB\\
BC &= FB-FC = \left(2-\sqrt3\right)AB
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. Greatly appreciated. Got it and love it.

Comment: Absolutely incredible. I am just marveling at the construction. Could you present any insights into the thought process to get to this solution. Did you also first solve it algebraically and then look for a construction to get to it. I am just trying to understand the reverse engineering process. I got the equations for AC and BC but could not visualize a way to get to it in a geometric fashion.

Comment: @NaveenSaxena There was already an ["algebraic" answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4513448/89922) here before I drew and typed my answer. Solving that "algebraically" is easy and so is a helpful tool to gain insight, even if you are looking for a more geometric answer.

Comment: @NaveenSaxena As MathFail commented under their answer, I wonder do you want to find (as in construct) point $C$ geometrically after learning the ratio $\sqrt3-1$ by magic, or do you want to find (as in prove) the ratio $\sqrt3-1$ geometrically that it satisfies the condition? Just looking for a construction is easier: from segment $AB$, construct only perpendicular line $EFG$, and lastly construct an equilateral triangle $\triangle ECG$ with $C$ between $AB$.

Answer (score 0):

Let point A be the origin, $A(0,0)$, and let point B be $B(b,0)$, so you want to find the coordinate of point $C(c,0)$

$$AB^2+BC^2=2AC^2\Rightarrow b^2+(c-b)^2=2c^2$$

Solve this quadratic equation and you get the coordinate of point C:

$$c=(-1+\sqrt{3})b,~~\text{or}~~c=(-1-\sqrt{3})b$$

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response and your help. I am actually looking for a euclidean geometry solution and not a solution that applies a combination of algebra and coordinate geometry,

Comment: Ok, but you can use this algebraic solution to construct the geometry solution, for example, $c=(-1+\sqrt{3})b$ means first you use length $AB$ as $b$ to construct $\sqrt{2}b$ then construct $\sqrt{3}b$, finally subtract $b$ and you get $AC$